# Mysql SUM always return 1 in php

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I'm running the following mysql query in php.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(profit) FROM customers;");
$sum_profit = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $sum_profit;"
```

and the response $sum_profit is returning is always 1. This while the table profit has been filled with the following:

```
profit
0.00
1.00
1.00
0.00
11.28
```

The type of the `profit` column is `double(10, 2)`. is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You are using  mysql_num_rows which returns number of rows. And that would be 1!

Comment: DOUBLE!?!? Surely DECIMAL!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysql_num_rows()` returns the number of rows returnd by your query. In this case it is one row. You're looking for any of the functions that returns a result set. An example would be [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(profit) FROM customers;");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(profit) as totalprofit FROM customers;");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[totalprofit];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That won't work. mysql_fetch_row returns int keys. You are looking for mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given. It needs to be mysql_fetch_row